# RxSwift - Concat only on condition

Tags: swift, rx-swift, reactive-cocoa

I have 2 stream which are being concatenated. If the first stream executes `onError` instead of `onComplete`, I shouldn't be concatenating the second stream.

example:

```
func updateEntity(entities: [Member]) -> Observable<[Result<Member>]> {
     let remoteUpdate = remoteStore.update(entities: entities)

     return remoteUpdate.concat(localStore.update(entities: entities))
}
```

I shouldn't be updating the `localStore` if `remoteUpdate` throws an error, onError is called in `remoteUpdate`

Update:

```
public override func update(entities: [PlaceAlert]) -> Observable<[Result<PlaceAlert>]> { 
    let remoteUpdate = remoteStore.update(entities: entities) 
    var entityPlaceHolder: [PlaceAlert] = entities 

    return remoteUpdate.catchError { _ in 
      entityPlaceHolder = [] 
      return localStore.update(entities: entityPlaceHolder)
    }.concat(localStore.update(entities: entityPlaceHolder)) 
}
```

Just tried improvising. would this make any difference? LocalUpdate with emptyArray does nothing if there is an error

Answer (score 0):

`concat` is not an if/then statement. Both `update`s are getting called at the same scope, it's just that the result won't reflect the localStore.update response if the remoteStore errors.

`catchError` is what you want in this context:

```
func updateEntity(entities: [Member]) -> Observable<[Result<Member>]> {
    let remoteUpdate = remoteStore.update(entities: entities)
    return remoteUpdate.catchError { _ in
        localStore.update(entities: entities)
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice. I would want to update the `localStore` only if `remoteStore` update is successful and on error just return `remoteStore` update's `Result`

Comment: In the question you said you *didn't* want that.